# react native trying to infinitely spin react logo

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to create the react logo infinite spinning loop using react native reanimated. I'm fairly new to mobile development and animations so the best I've done so far is the following. It spins 180 degrees and goes back to its start infinitely. I know why it rotates back (because the initial value is 0) and I know that the negative 2 makes it spin forever.

I don't know how to fix it though, any ideas?

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Animated as NativeAnimated,
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withRepeat,
  withTiming,
} from "react-native-reanimated";

const ReactLogo = () => {
  const spin = useSharedValue(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    spin.value = withRepeat(withTiming(360, { duration: 5000 }), -2, true);
  });
  const stylez = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      position: "absolute",
      top: 100,
      transform: [
        {
          rotateZ: `${spin.value}deg`,
        },
      ],
    };
  });

  return (
    <Animated.View style={stylez}>
      <Text>
        <FontAwesome5 name="react" size={64} color="black" />
      </Text>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

export default ReactLogo;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: In this line `spin.value = withRepeat(withTiming(360, { duration: 5000 }), -2, true);`, change the last parameter from `true` to `false`. That parameter represents `reverse` which means that whether to animate it back to the initial value or not. Read more [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/animations/withRepeat#reverse-)

Comment: That did fix one issue, now it's behaving in another unexpected way and speeding up after some time. Any idea how to make it rotate at the same speed infinitely?

Comment: Your question includes, `why it rotates back`. This modification solves that issue. You'll have to find out a logic of keeping the speed same throughout the animation.

Comment: Understood, post your answer, I'll upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make the `reverse` flag to false.

In case of `reverse = true`

- Animation Starts from 0 to 360
- Reaches 360
- Sets the `spin.value = 0` (with Timing Configuration)
- Again animates from 0 to 360.

But, In case of `reverse = false`

- Animation Starts from 0 to 360
- Reaches 360
- Sets the `spin.value = 0` (without Timing Configuration)
- Again animates from 0 to 360.

So, setting `reverse` flag to false will solve your issue.

```
spin.value = withRepeat(withTiming(360, { duration: 5000 }), -2, false);
```